# rails3 app ENV not being recognized as production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, production

I set up my rails app on my linode VPS, phusion passenger is installed and working, so is mysql (I know this cause my friend currently is running 2 production apps on it with the same set up). The VPS is running Ubuntu 10.10 and I'm using apache2 with passenger.

I SFTP'd the app to the server, bundle updated, set up my virtual host and specified RailsEnv to be production and paths are all accurate.

I then restarted the server (as root) with 
    apachectl -k restart
tried to rake db:migrate and it didn't do anything, so I figured it was because the environment didn't get changed, which is exactly what happend. If I go into the rails console and type Rails.env it gives me development.

I have no idea why, I did everything that should set it to production? Anyone know what I may have missed? Is there somewhere in the app where I'm supposed to change something to say production environment? I thought that only had to be done in rails 2.x

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Comment: When you say you did `rake db:migrate` and `rails console`, is that all you typed?  Or did you append `RAILS_ENV=production` to the commands?  Or did you set your RAILS_ENV environment variable to `production`?

Comment: Where do I set the RAILS_ENV environment.. everything I've read says that's only for rails 2.x and not rails 3. This is why I'm not sure what to do. But Phusion Passenger and everything else I've read says you just need to set it in your virtual host file, by doing "RailsEnv production" which I did

Comment: an no, I didn't append RAILS_ENV=production to the commands, but even if I did, that'd only work for those commands, but my server would not be serving my app in production

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `RailsEnv` setting is only for Passenger's use.  It doesn't affect the commands you type in the shell.

Use

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

and

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails console
```

Or set the `RAILS_ENV` environment variable in your login shell to `production` so that you don't have to append `RAILS_ENV=production` to the commands you issue:

```
export RAILS_ENV=production
```

(exact command may vary depending on which shell you use; the above works in bash)

Comment: Thanks guys, you shed some light on that. Looks like I have another issue on my hands, passengers telling me I have some syntax error in my application helper, but it probably has to do with gem issues or something

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track; all you need to do to actually run the app in production mode is set the RailsEnv as you did, assuming you are running the app using Passenger. However, to run the database migrations you need to tell Rails what environment to run within.

The rails console command defaults to the 'development' environment by default. The same goes for running database migrations.

To run the migrations on your production environment you need to run the command as such:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

And to run the console in production mode, you need to run the console using the command:

```
rails console production
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want this variable to be set automatically, put `RAILS_ENV=production`at the end of your `~/.bashrc` file. (This only works with a bash terminal)

Then open a new terminal, or restart your ssh connection.